# Cannot serve script files linked to html file with koa

Tags: node.js, koa

I am missing something really obvious related to serving static files in HTTP.

I can link script files from a CDN by `<script>` tags in my documents `<head>`. However I cannot link my own javascript files that reside in a `/components` folder on my HTTP server root directory, run by koa.js. I know this by checking the browser inspector resources, there are CDN delivered files but no trace of latter.

The files that is needed to be linked to the html file below are `components/questionbox.js` and `components/main.js`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Questions, Home</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Universal JS-ClientSide (1/3): Load React, ReactDOM and the react component to be mounted to the mount node. -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src"/questionbox.js"></script>
    <!-- Universal JS-ClientSide (1/3): Load React, ReactDOM and the react component to be mounted to the mount node. -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.5/marked.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Universal JS-ServerSide&ClientSide (2/3): Create a mount node to mount the react component to. -->
    <div id="mount-node"><%- markup %></div>
    <!-- Universal JS-ServerSide&ClientSide (2/3): Create a mount node to mount the react component to. -->

    <!--script id="jsonifiedInitialProps" type="application/json">
        {{{ jsonifiedInitialProps }}}
    </script-->

    <script type="text/babel">

        // Universal JS-ClientSide (3/3): Mount the react component to the mount node.
        ReactDOM.render(<QuestionBox />, document.getElementById('mount-node'));
        // Universal JS-ClientSide (3/3): Mount the react component to the mount node.

    </script>
    <script src"/main.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Related code fragment on my server code is as follows; `app.use(static(__dirname + '/components'));` which uses [`koa-static`](https://github.com/koajs/static) npm module.

More to my surprise `css` files that are in the same folder can be linked successfully to the html file.

What can be the issue here? What is the thing that I miss on such a basic topic of HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the src attribute of the script tags linking to those two javascript files, the equal sign `=` is missing from them.

`<script src="questionbox.js"></script>`

`<script src="main.js"></script>`

Comment: I cannot believe how I can ruin hours for such a mistake.